# Resize a polygon drawn with Numpy and OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I got a polygon of outer lip from reading face landmarks using dlib and OpenCV as a numpy array of shape `(1, 13, 2)`

Now, I don't want to draw this polygon but instead draw a scaled version of this polygon, let say by increase by 2 times, onto a black image.

I came across `cv2.resize()` but it seems to accept an image for scaling. Giving in the numpy array of points directly to `cv.resize()` gave this error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (func != 0) in cv::hal::resize

So, my question is, how to scale first and then draw? Do I have to manually select the upper half and translate the points and separately translate the lower half since the both need translation in different directions. Or is there some way I can use the `cv2.resize` directly?

Comment: simply multiply each coordinate by your scaling factor, and draw it as usual

Comment: But I don't want the position to change. So, scale it and put it back at the same position?

Comment: "but it seems to accept an image for scaling" -- well, the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize#cv2.resize) is quite straightforward about this: "Resizes an image."

Comment: It is indeed. So, what to use instead?

Comment: Which _position_ doesn't change?

Comment: The position of the polygon changes, right? Like, translates.

Comment: Which is the coordinate you don't want to change? the center of mass maybe?

Comment: In my case, the left most point should be on the y axis, the top most point on the x axis. But, I guess I can just translate with something like `np.array - translation`

Comment: If it doesn't just upscale, you might want to position them in 0 space, apply scale and then reposition them.

Comment: What is the 0 space?

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed He means that you should find the center of your polygon (x, y), translate the polygon by (-x, -y) apply the scale, then translate it back to (x, y).

Answer (score 0):

```
def scale(image, coords):
    '''
    image: cv2 image
    corods: e.g. [(ax, ay), (bx, by), (cx, cy), (dx, dy)]
    '''
    scale = 2
    ow, oh, och = image.shape

    scaled_img = cv2.resize(image,None,fx=scale,fy=scale)
    w, h, ch = scaled_img.shape
    M = cv2.getAffineTransform(np.float32([[ow, 0], [ow, oh], [0, oh]]), np.float32([[w, 0], [w, h], [0, h]]))
    newpointlist = []

    npcoords = np.array([coords], np.int32)
    scaledpoints = cv2.transform(npcoords,M)
    for p in scaledpoints[0]:
        newpointlist.append(p)

    #debugging pics
    for point in newpointlist:
        cv2.circle(scaled_img, (int(point[0]), int(point[1])), 5, (0,0,255), -1)

    cv2.imshow('img', scaled_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

something like this could work. I've used this to scale both the image and some points within that image.